# Dependent care FSA: Paying a grandparent for providing childcare?

Tags: united-states, family, child-care, fsa

I have a dependent care FSA account that I set up. Both my wife and I are employed.

I would like to use this money to pay for my child's care at home by his grandmother.

I already know that I can use the money to pay her, but our situation is a bit complex - she is not a U.S. Citizen and does not have a SSN. It's also important to point out that she only plans to use the money towards her airfare cost (she would never take money from us for anything more than that).

Please advise if we can use the FSA in our situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is she on a visa that allows employment?